# How do I slow my cursor on laptop so I can control it better

Tags: acer

When I use the cursor it is to fast for me to control, I have tried to see if there was any way to control it using the settings menu. But I can not find anything to suit my needs.

I need to know how I can slow down my cursor (the little arrow) on touch pad.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Goto

- Settings
- Mouse And Touchpad

Then Select The *Pointer Speed*.
And You're Done.

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings and go to Mouse and Touchpad.

There should be a slider for pointer speed. Adjust it till you are comfortable.